# How can I prematurely exit __enter__ and skip the with block in Python?

Tags: python, class

I've been trying to find a way to completely exit/skip my `with BaseObject.ethernet_device(ip_addr) as obj:` code block if there are errors in the `__enter__` function.

In the example below this would be if the device is not present on the network. Any solutions would hopefully go in place of the line `return None` (which I know is not what's needed).

```
class BaseObject(object):
    @class_method
    def ethernet_device(cls, host:str):
        return EthernetDevice(host)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self._inst.close()
```

```
class EthernetDevice(BaseObject):
    def __init__(self, host: str):
        self._host = host

    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            socket.inet_ntoa(self._host)
            ip_addr = self._host
        except:
            logger.debug(f'{self._host} is not a valid IP address: trying as a hostname')
            try:
                logger.debug(f"Trying to resolve host {self._host}")
                ip_addr = socket.gethostbyname(self._host)
            except socket.gaierror:
                logger.error(f"Couldn't resolve host {self._host}")
                return None

        self._inst = vxi11.Instrument(ip_addr)

        return super().__enter__()
```

Usage:

```
with BaseObject.ethernet_device(ip_addr) as device:
   print(device.id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only answer here is to raise an exception inside `__enter__`; `__exit__` will always run if `__enter__` exits without an exception (assuming you don't manage to segfault the interpreter or call `os._exit` to intentionally kill the program without running cleanup blocks).

This will put it on the caller to catch the exception (wrapping the `with` with a `try`/`except`) to prevent it bubbling through the rest of the program.

If the caller doesn't like indenting the whole block for this, they can narrow the scope using [an `ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack), but that's the only "improvement" available, and it still requires `__enter__` to raise an exception:

```
with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    try:
        device = stack.enter_context(BaseObject.ethernet_device(ip_addr)
    except CustomException:
        return  # Or do something else to skip remaining code
    # Rest of code using device

# device is cleaned up for you if it exists
```